# Flutter_stripe default payment sheet inside Google pay option is not showing

Tags: flutter, stripes

I have used flutter_stripe SDK 5.0.0 and and I am trying to implement google pay functionality in default sheet. also I have enable google pay option inside SetupPaymentSheetParameters

final googlePaySupported = await Stripe.instance.isGooglePaySupported(IsGooglePaySupportedParams());

This is return True value.

```
      await Stripe.instance
          .initPaymentSheet(
        paymentSheetParameters: SetupPaymentSheetParameters(
          // Main params
          paymentIntentClientSecret:
              apiPaymentResponse.data!.data!.paymentIntent,
          merchantDisplayName: 'My Store ',
          // Customer params
          customerId: apiPaymentResponse.data!.data!.customer,
          customerEphemeralKeySecret:
              apiPaymentResponse.data!.data!.ephemeralKey,

          // Extra params
          applePay: const PaymentSheetApplePay(
            merchantCountryCode: 'DE',
          ),
          googlePay: const PaymentSheetGooglePay(
              merchantCountryCode: 'US', testEnv: true, currencyCode: "DE"),
          style: ThemeMode.system,
          billingDetails: billingDetails,
        ),
      )
          .then((value) async {
        loaderClose();
        confirmPayment(
          context: context,
          state: state,
        );
      });
```

await Stripe.instance.presentPaymentSheet();